# React doesn't render when applied from CDN

Tags: reactjs, dns

I know how to set up a React project using npm, yeoman and it works fine. 
When I follow this tutorial
    http://danprince.github.io/learn-react/lessons/ex1.html and apply React from CDN, it also works - but it's an old version. If I try to apply a new version of React via CDN, I can't figure out how to render *ANYTHING* on the screen. For example, what's wrong with the following code?:

react:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js'>
```

html:

```
<body>

<div id="root"> </div>

</body>
```

js (based on Code School tutorial exaple):

```
class StoryBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return( <div>Story Box</div> );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <StoryBox />, document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]  javascript.js:3:16

Answer (score 0):

Since `react` [`v15.6.0`](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v15.6.0) the `ReactDOM` module has been moved to a separate package add this to below your `react` `<script ... />` tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Snippet:

```js
class StoryBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return( <div>Story Box</div> );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <StoryBox />, document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"> </div>
```

*I think you should look at some updated react tutorials e.g. 
[Simple React Development in 2017](https://hackernoon.com/simple-react-development-in-2017-113bd563691f)*

Comment: ok good point, thanks, but still i got no render and inspector says: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]  javascript.js:3:16

Comment: You need to use a bundler like `Babel` to correctly convert your `ES6/2015` code to normal javascript as browsers are not able to understand this code atm. I would start again by following the guide i linked in my answer.