# React doesn't render components or code (CDN import version)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, cdn

In essence, I cannot study React because I stacked on a basic problem. **Sorry I am a newbie, do not judge strong.** Message does not show, the code is simple, I do not understand what's wrong with importing CDN.
Among other things, this post doesn't answer my question:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738372/react-doesnt-render-when-applied-from-cdn)

Here is my full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    class StoryBox extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return( <div>Story Box</div> );
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        <StoryBox />, document.getElementById('root')
    );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to see a simple message, but the code simply does not work, nor it gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [`type="text/jsx"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-standalone#script-tags) attribute as:

> When loaded in a browser, @babel/standalone will automatically compile and execute all script tags with type text/babel or text/jsx - [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-standalone#script-tags)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/jsx"> 
      class StoryBox extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return <div>Story Box</div>;
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox />, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the second answer I found by similarity, it's to add type="type/babel" to above class StoryBox,

Man, but I asked, please do not judge to strongly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may not give you an error in the console, but if you look at the document window the script is rendering as html...
This is due to a missing opening tag.  If you're new to programming check out vs code and/or maybe run a linter, it'll catch those errors and small typos making debugging and troubleshooting way quicker and easier!

```
<script> /** added this opening tag */
class StoryBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return( <div>Story Box</div> );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <StoryBox />, document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```